# How to speedup Hibernate DML statements for one-to-many associations

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have been trying to optimize a hibernate application and one of the biggest problems I have faced with Hibernates efficiency is its tendency to execute n+1 queries for a simple crud operation with child entities. I have been able to prevent n+1 queries for select operations by using `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` on the child entity (many-to-one side), but that does not affect update/insert/delete queries. Here is a sample of the relevant entities and properties:

```
// parent entity for Mean and Covariance entities
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "belief")
public class Belief implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    // surrogate key
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "belief_id", unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    // other properties...

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.beliefId", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Mean> means = new ArrayList<>();

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.beliefId", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Covariance> covariances = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "mean")
public class Mean implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    // composite key
    @EmbeddedId
    private MeanPK pk = new MeanPK(this);

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "belief_id", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Belief belief;

    // other properties...
}

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "covariance")
public class Covariance implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    // composite key
    @EmbeddedId
    private CovariancePK pk = new CovariancePK(this);

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "belief_id", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Belief belief;

    // other properties...
}
```

So when I execute `session.delete(belief);`, the logs show that a separate delete statement is executed for every covariance and mean that the belief entity may have referenced. Here is an example of the log:

```
Hibernate: select belief0_.belief_id as belief_i1_0_0_, belief0_.after_comb as after_co2_0_0_, belief0_.description as descript3_0_0_, belief0_.name as name4_0_0_, belief0_.project_id as project_7_0_0_, belief0_.type as type5_0_0_, belief0_.version as version6_0_0_ from belief belief0_ where belief0_.belief_id=?
Hibernate: select covariance0_.belief_id as belief_i1_0_0_, covariance0_.belief_id as belief_i1_1_0_, covariance0_.col_variable_id as col_vari2_1_0_, covariance0_.row_variable_id as row_vari3_1_0_, covariance0_.belief_id as belief_i1_1_1_, covariance0_.col_variable_id as col_vari2_1_1_, covariance0_.row_variable_id as row_vari3_1_1_, covariance0_.variance as variance4_1_1_, covariance0_.version as version5_1_1_, variable1_.variable_id as variable1_5_2_, variable1_.definition as definiti2_5_2_, variable1_.description as descript3_5_2_, variable1_.name as name4_5_2_, variable1_.project_id as project_6_5_2_, variable1_.version as version5_5_2_, variable2_.variable_id as variable1_5_3_, variable2_.definition as definiti2_5_3_, variable2_.description as descript3_5_3_, variable2_.name as name4_5_3_, variable2_.project_id as project_6_5_3_, variable2_.version as version5_5_3_ from covariance covariance0_ inner join variable variable1_ on covariance0_.col_variable_id=variable1_.variable_id inner join variable variable2_ on covariance0_.row_variable_id=variable2_.variable_id where covariance0_.belief_id=?
Hibernate: select means0_.belief_id as belief_i1_0_0_, means0_.belief_id as belief_i1_2_0_, means0_.variable_id as variable2_2_0_, means0_.belief_id as belief_i1_2_1_, means0_.variable_id as variable2_2_1_, means0_.mean as mean3_2_1_, means0_.swept as swept4_2_1_, means0_.version as version5_2_1_, variable1_.variable_id as variable1_5_2_, variable1_.definition as definiti2_5_2_, variable1_.description as descript3_5_2_, variable1_.name as name4_5_2_, variable1_.project_id as project_6_5_2_, variable1_.version as version5_5_2_ from mean means0_ inner join variable variable1_ on means0_.variable_id=variable1_.variable_id where means0_.belief_id=?
Hibernate: delete from covariance where belief_id=? and col_variable_id=? and row_variable_id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from covariance where belief_id=? and col_variable_id=? and row_variable_id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from mean where belief_id=? and variable_id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from mean where belief_id=? and variable_id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from mean where belief_id=? and variable_id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from mean where belief_id=? and variable_id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from mean where belief_id=? and variable_id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from belief where belief_id=? and version=?
```

I have done a good amount of googling for a fix for this n+1 issue, and I have only found solutions for select operations, and not cascading insert/update/delete operations.
Does anyone have an idea as to how this can be fixed and optimized?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate translates [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/) to DML statements, that's why you have one DELETE statement for each entity that gets deleted.

You [shouldn't use EAGER fetching](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/), since a query-base fetching policy is always more flexible and yields the best performance. The associations should be `LAZY` and you should use the `JOIN FETCH` directive for retrieving just the relations you need for each particular business case.

You should also enable statement batching for:

- [INSERT and UPDATE statements](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/)
- [DELETE statements](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-delete-statements-with-hibernate/)

If you have a write-intensive application, you could use bulk statements using the bulk `UPDATE/DELETE` `HQL/JPQL` support.

Comment: Ahhh statement batching is what I was looking for! This application may potentially insert/update/delete hundreds of rows at a time, so this would be even more beneficial. I am going to try out statement batching now. Great articles by the way!

Comment: Why is the batch size recommended to be between 5 and 50? why not more? Why is there a recommended limit? doesn't that mean that a batch update of 500 entities, and a batch size of 50, there would be 10 separate queries?

Comment: It's about database round-trips. The larger the batch size, the less round-trips, but more memory will be required on both the client-side and the database side. Like always, the best advice is to measure against production data and see which batch size yields the best performance.

Comment: Is there a way to get hibernate to use statement batching when it is cascading operations to a collection of child entities as I have with the Mean and Covariance entities? Or do I have to manually loop the child entities and do the save/update/delete operations for each entity while doing flush and clear on each batch size iteration as you had in your tests?

Comment: The flush and clear is useful when doing batch inserts. Cascading is covered in my articles too.

Comment: I read that flush and clear should also be done when doing batch updates. Is this true? So in my case, If I want to batch insert/update the child Mean and Covariance entities, I will have to iterate them manually so that I can handle flush and clear? I saw that cascading was only discussed for batch deletes in your articles. Can you cascade batch updates and inserts as well?

Comment: You don't need to clear the Session for update and deletes. The cascade should work just fine. Cascade updates are covered as well in my article. Check the first one as see the CascadeType.ALL.

Comment: Ok I see. Well after a lot of debugging, and looking through the trace logs, I realized that it was actually doing the batch operations properly. The hibernate sql output did not change as it did in your tests, so that threw me off.  Thanks for all your help! Hopefully this solves any efficiency problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically at the point where the expected Hibernate magic has ended since a while and ended in the reality of OR-Mapping.

You can remove the FetchType.Lazy from OneToMany, because thats the default value. The FetchType.Eager would be the way to overcome the n+1 problem for select statements. You are also not doing this (or lets say you mix hibernate and jpa stuff not sure what wins in that case). The question why do you want to do a batch delete? If yes, than do so but do not expect that hibernate does the decision for you. Keep in mind that a delete by a collection of ids does probably not fire cascade and orphan removal.
If you expect a large amount of entries in that Lists than it is time to refactor your mapping.

**!!!BUT MOST IMPORTANT!!!**

You have multiple things in your mapping, which seem to have a much higher negative performance impact and will cause in certain situations unexpected behaviour. It seems for me that you want to performance optimize a certain thing which is not the biggest issue. As long as you do not have a performance issue with the delete please do not do anything.

- Mixed two fetch systems
- High cascade usage - why were this decision been made. Was their really a thought process behind that? Or solved it a problem for you which could be resolved in a cleaner way by handling them manually.
- Is there a specific reason for that EmbeddedId stuff which could not be handled by a simple Long id? Seems a bit over the top for me.
- I don't question that JoinColumn insertable etc stuff. I just hope that there is a reason behind that.

Comment: 1) FetchType is different from FetchMode.  
2) What is wrong with using CascadeType.ALL? what cascade types would you commonly use for a standard parent/child relationship?  
3) The EmbeddedId is needed because the underlying schema uses composite keys for optimal normalization, and I cannot alter the schema. And the EmbeddedId stuff is not the problem. That works fine.  
4) the insertable and updatable attributes to JoinColumn makes sense because in this case, the child entity should never change its parent.

Comment: Usually I use zero Cascade operations and do the this via an appropriate service layer. Is a bit more code to do in the first place, but less problems in the long run. One reason for this is that later maybe someone needs to do something with an entity before its deleted or updated (like fire an event). Than it might be necessary to fix multiple locations to do that. Thats just one example of why I avoid cascade.

Comment: I checked what hibernate does with @FetchMode Join and FetchType.Lazy. My test resulted in that it behaves the same as with FetchType.Eager. From the official documentation of hibernate: "JOIN (use a SQL JOIN to load the association while loading the owner entity). JOIN overrides any lazy attribute (an association loaded through a JOIN strategy cannot be lazy)"

Comment: You are right. There is no point for me to define FetchType.LAZY there because it will just be ignored due to FetchMode.JOIN. Also, LAZY is the default so I might as well remove it everywhere.

Comment: Maybe a bit of additional information. Keep in mind that FetchMode.Join acts like FetchType.EAGER when doing a query on your own. This means FetchMode.Join is only an advantage for em.find(class,key) and not for em.createQuery(query)